# backbone.js click and blur events

Tags: events, click, backbone.js, blur

I'm having some trouble with blur and click events in backbone.  I have a view (code below) that creates a little search entry div with a button.  I pop open this div and put focus on the entry field.  If someone clicks off (blur) I notify a parent view to close this one.  If they click on the button I'll initiate a search.

The blur behavior works fine, however when I click on the button I also get a blur event and can't get the click event.  Have I got this structured right?

BTW, some other posts have suggested things like adding timers to the div in case its being closed before the click event fires.  I can comment out the close completely and still only get the blur event.  Do these only fire one at a time on some kind of first-com-first-served basis?

```
PB_SearchEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<div id='searchEntry' class='searchEntry'><input id='part'></input><button id='findit'>Search</button></div>"),
    events: {
        "click button": "find",
        "blur #part": "close"
    },
    initialize: function(args) {
        this.dad = args.dad;
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    close: function(event){ this.dad.close(); },
    find: function() {
        alert("Find!");
    }
});
```

Comment: the events you bind to in the `events` list are handled by jquery, and backbone provides the callback method and wires up the callback. suggest making this work with just jquery first, and then you should be able to get it working with backbone just fine

Comment: Yes, that was the trick.  Thanks!  Based on this info I found this post that provided the final clue how to make this work: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-blur

Comment: Can you post what the final clue was, and how it helped you solve your problem?

Comment: This question is nearly as old as Backbone itself, yet the same code could still be written today and it would have the same problem for the same reasons. Hence, I believe a solution would also still be useful and educative, so I just wrote an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem was, but here is the [jsbin code](http://jsbin.com/ijaric).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the question being 11 years old, it is still possible to run into this situation with current versions of Backbone, Underscore and jQuery, and the solution is also still the same.

Let us start with a reproduction of the problem in a runnable snippet. Below, I copied the code from the question and added some mock code. To reproduce, please click "Run code snippet", then manually focus the text input by clicking inside it, and then click the button. You will see that the input field and the button disappear again and the `alert('Find!')` line does not run:

```js
var PB_SearchEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<div id='searchEntry' class='searchEntry'><input id='part'></input><button id='findit'>Search</button></div>"),
    events: {
        "click button": "find",
        "blur #part": "close"
    },
    initialize: function(args) {
        this.dad = args.dad;
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    close: function(event){
        this.dad.close();
    },
    find: function() {
        alert("Find!");
    }
});

var MockDadView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.search = new PB_SearchEntryView({
            dad: this
        }).render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.search.el);
        return this;
    },
    close: function() {
        this.search.remove();
    }
});

var view = new MockDadView().render();
view.$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/backbone@1.4.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

The reason is as follows. An action by the user will often trigger many different types of events. In this case, clicking the button may be expected to trigger all of the following events:

1. `blur` on the `<input>` element.
2. `change` on the `<input>` element (only if the user was typing into it just before clicking the button; in other words, if the `blur` was preceded by an `input` event).
3. `mousedown` on the `<button>` element.
4. `mouseup` on the `<button>` element.
5. `click` on the `<button>` element.
6. `submit` on a parent `<form>` element, if there is one (because we did not set the the `type` attribute of the `<button>` and it defaults to `submit`).

The above order is standardized, because this order is most useful for implementing user-friendly interactive forms. In particular, `blur` and `change` on the `<input>` trigger before any events on the `<button>`, because those events are potentially good opportunities to validate the user's input prior to taking further form processing steps. Likewise, the `<button>` events trigger before the `submit` of the entire `<form>`, because you might want to do final whole-form validation or other preprocessing before finally actually submitting the form.

Handlers for these events are immediately invoked by the browser, and the call stack is allowed to unwind completely before the next user event is triggered. This is JavaScript's famous event loop at play. Hence, the following things happen when we click the button in the problematic snippet above:

1. The `blur` event fires.
2. The `close` method of our `PB_SearchEntryView` instance is invoked.
3. The `close` method of our `MockDadView` is invoked.
4. The `remove` method of our `PB_SearchEntryView` instance is invoked.
5. The HTML element of our `PB_SearchEntryView` instance is removed from the `DOM` and its event bindings are deleted (this is the default behavior of the `remove` prototype method of `Backbone.View`).
6. The methods invoked above return in reverse order.
7. The `click` event on the `<button>` is never triggered, because the element has been removed from the DOM in step 5.
8. (Even if the `click` event was triggered in step 7, the `find` method of our `PB_SearchEntryView` instance would still not be invoked, because the event binding was undone in step 5.)

Hence, if we still want the `find` method to be invoked after the `blur` has been handled, we need to prevent the `remove` method from being invoked in the meanwhile. A straightforward and valid way to do this, is to delay the call to `this.dad.close`. A suitable delay is about 50 milliseconds; this is long enough to ensure that the `click` event of the `<button>` is triggered first and short enough that the user does not notice it. We can even cancel the delayed call in order to keep the search view open when the button is clicked. In the snippet below, I changed the `close` and `find` methods to illustrate how this can be done and added comments to explain the mechanics:

```js
var PB_SearchEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<div id='searchEntry' class='searchEntry'><input id='part'></input><button id='findit'>Search</button></div>"),
    events: {
        "click button": "find",
        "blur #part": "close"
    },
    initialize: function(args) {
        this.dad = args.dad;
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    close: function(event){
        // Short way to refer to this.dad.
        var dad = this.dad;
        // The method of this.dad we want to be
        // invoked later. When saving it to a
        // variable, we need to bind it so that
        // the `this` variable points to this.dad
        // when it is invoked.
        var askDadToClose = dad.close.bind(dad);
        // Invoke dad's close method with a 50 ms
        // delay. Save a handle that enables us
        // to cancel the call in the find method.
        this.willClose = setTimeout(askDadToClose, 50);
    },
    find: function() {
        alert("Find!");
        // If you still want the search view to
        // close after performing the search,
        // remove the `if` block below.
        if (this.willClose != null) {
            clearTimeout(this.willClose);
            delete this.willClose;
        }
    }
});

var MockDadView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.search = new PB_SearchEntryView({
            dad: this
        }).render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.search.el);
        return this;
    },
    close: function() {
        this.search.remove();
    }
});

var view = new MockDadView().render();
view.$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/backbone@1.4.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

### Bonus material

The question also asked whether the code was structured right. Below is a third version of the snippet, in which I made three changes that I think would be improvements:

1. The child view (`PB_SearchEntryView`) no longer knows about its parent view. Instead of invoking a method on the parent, it simply triggers an event. It is up to other components of the application to listen for that event and handle it. This reduces coupling of components and generally makes applications easier to test and maintain. (For loose coupling of long-distance communication, I recommend using [backbone.radio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone.radio).)
2. Instead of listening for the `click` event on a `<button>`, listen for a `submit` event on a `<form>`. This is more semantic and appropriate when submitting a form is exactly what we are doing. This also enables the user to trigger the same event handler by pressing the return key while typing into the `<input>` element. This does require that the `<button type=submit>` is inside a `<form>` element, which is why we set the `tagName` of the view to `form`.
3. Put the views in charge of rendering themselves. Generally, the view itself knows best when to change its internal HTML structure and generally, this is both when it is first created and whenever its model or collection changes (if any). Making external components responsibe for rendering is usually an antipattern, unless rendering is really expensive (for example if rendering a map or a complex visualization).

```js
var PB_SearchEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // This is a form, so it can be submitted.
    tagName: 'form',
    template: _.template("<div id='searchEntry' class='searchEntry'><input id='part'></input><button id='findit'>Search</button></div>"),
    events: {
        // Handle submit rather than a button click.
        "submit": "find",
        "blur #part": "close"
    },
    initialize: function(args) {
        // self-render on initialize
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    close: function(event){
        // Like before, we save a method for later,
        // but this time it is our own trigger
        // method and we bind two additional
        // arguments. This view does not need to
        // know what happens with its 'close' event.
        var triggerClose = this.trigger.bind(this, 'close', this);
        // Delay as before.
        this.willClose = setTimeout(triggerClose, 50);
    },
    find: function(event) {
        // Since this is now a proper submit
        // handler, we need to prevent the default
        // behavior of reloading the page.
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Find!");
        if (this.willClose != null) {
            clearTimeout(this.willClose);
            delete this.willClose;
        }
    }
});

var MockDadView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // This view owns an instance of the above
        // view and knows what to do with its
        // 'close' event.
        this.search = new PB_SearchEntryView();
        this.search.on('close', this.close, this);
        // self-render on initialize
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.search.el);
        return this;
    },
    close: function() {
        this.search.remove();
    }
});

var view = new MockDadView();
view.$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/backbone@1.4.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

There is a slight catch with using the above snippet, at least in Safari: if I submit the form by pretting the return key, the `find` method is still invoked, but the form is also removed. I suspect Safari is triggering a new `blur` event after closing the alert in this case. Solving that would be enough material for another question!